# Displaying text messages from array in after delay of 3 seconds in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to display messages from array one after another. But it only shows last message in array. I have used start StartCoroutine() to call the  IEnumerator in which code delays after 3 seconds. But after delaying only last message in array is displaying.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class WelcomeMessage : MonoBehaviour {

    private string startMessage="Hello Player,It's Time to start Learning the Video Game Development";
    private string[] messages = { "Now, First Complete Your First Assingment","Find Treasure","Kill them" }; 

    public GameObject canvas;

    public Text Message;
    void Start () {
        setInitialization();
        showMessage();
    }

    void setInitialization() 
    {
        Message = GameObject.Find("welcomeMessage").GetComponent<Text>();


    }
    void showMessage() 
    {

        Message.text = startMessage;
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.Length; i++)
        {
            StartCoroutine(disableCanvas(messages[i]));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator disableCanvas(string msg) 
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        Message.resizeTextForBestFit = false;
        Message.fontSize = 20;
        Message.text = msg;

        Message.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you have a question you have no selected as the answer even though it solved your problem. If people answer your question and it solved your problem, you select their answer as the solution. One exception is if the problem is not solved.

Comment: I do not know from where to select answer as solution.

Comment: Click on the check mark on the top left of the answer. 
http://i.imgur.com/GWuYsNn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's a simple logic error. You start three coroutines at same time, so the `Message` will be set to the last one.
2. What you want to do is set the `Message` one by one.

   ```
   IEnumerator showMessage( string[] msgs /*, firstTime, secondTime */ )
   {
       // Here for keeping to display the start message.
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(firstTime);

       for ( int i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++ )
       {
           // Set Message Expressions

           // Here for keeping to display the previous message
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondTime);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Do not use `GameObject.Find()` in your Unity scripts. ( You can google a lot of contents about this tip. )

Comment: He is doing `GameObject.Find()` once in the `Start` function and that is totally fine. It is bad if you do every frame which is not the case here...

Answer (score 0):

The first text is displayed and immediately **overwritten** by the second text because there is no wait in the for loop.

You fix it by changing your `IEnumerator disableCanvas(string msg)` to   `IEnumerator disableCanvas(string []msg)` then do the `for` loop inside the disableCanvas function and **wait** after each loop. This will **guarantee** that each text will be **displayed**.

You new code:

```
    void Start()
    {
        setInitialization();
        showMessage();
    }

    void setInitialization()
    {
        Message = GameObject.Find("welcomeMessage").GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void showMessage()
    {

        StartCoroutine(disableCanvas(messages));
    }

    IEnumerator disableCanvas(string[] msg)
    {
        //Waiting time(Change to whatever value)
        float waitTime = 3;

        //Display the first message that is NOT in the array
        Message.text = startMessage;

        //Wait before starting to display each message in the array
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);


        for (int i = 0; i < msg.Length; i++)
        {
            Message.resizeTextForBestFit = false;
            Message.fontSize = 20;
            Message.text = msg[i];

            Message.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }
```